# access to shared with me drive folder in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm new to google colaboration
My team is doing a miniproject together, so my partner built a drive folder and shared it with me. The problem is that her code is to link to the file in her 'My Drive'

While she shares with me only the "miniproject" folder, thus when I run the code on the file in it, it will get error because of wrong path.

Her code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/miniproject/zoo6.csv")
```

The code I need to run on my account:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/miniproject/zoo6.csv")
```

(since I made a shortcut to my My Drive)

How can I run the code by my drive account on her drive folder?

Answer (score 0):

there currently exists some workarounds by adding the files to your drive though this is less than ideal. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351852/accessing-shared-with-me-with-colab)

Comment: I did made a shortcut into my drive, but it'll work only when I create a same path with my friend path