# Accessing a Shared Google Drive Directory in Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

How do I access a publicly shared google drive directory in Colab? One option is to:

1. Go to `Shared with Me`
2. Right click on the directory and select `Add a shortcut to drive`
3. Access the directory the normal way in Colab, inside `/content/drive/My Drive/`

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

But this has the disadvantage that every user who accesses a notebook I share with them has to go through this process. Any way making this simpler?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351852/accessing-shared-with-me-with-colab